# Extra cost for special shipping country

Tags: checkout, shipping, country-regions

Did any of you know a way to set a extra cost for a special country.
Like if customer is from sweden add + 40 USD.

**So at the checkout summery:**
Item Cost - 150 USD 
Shipping Cost - 60 USD

***+ Extra Cost for EU import - 40 USD***

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento, you can have this functionality pretty simply. There is a shipping method named ‘Table Rates‘. You can adjust the country specific shipping rates from it.

These are the steps to follow

– Go to System –> Configuration –> SALES –> Shipping Methods –> Table Rates -> Select ‘Enabled‘ to ‘Yes’

You will see as in the following figure:

[image]

– For your setup we will need = ‘Price vs. Destination’

– Click ‘Export CSV‘ and a csv file is downloaded with the required headers like country, region, shipping price, etc.

– Fill the csv with the shipping rate and country name. For example, see the following figure:

[image]

– The asterik (*) in region and postal code column means that the shipping price is applicable for all regions and postal code respectively.

– The zero (0) in order subtotal means that the shipping price is applicable for all orders whose subtotal is greater than zero.

– Now, Import the .csv you just filled out and save it

Done